# To test, using a backtracking algorithm, if a mouse can escape from a rectangular maze

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, stack, nodes

This program has is meant to create and solve a mouse escape route from a maze, by reading from a text file.There is a Maze class which is basically a 2D array of MazeElements, the MazeElements contains a char variable and a position object; the Position holds the co-ordinates of each element on the 2D-array.
So far, the program effectively reads in and creates the 2D array. The problem lies in the backTracking algorithm. I am using a stack to implement the back track but the backtrack seems to only loop once from the output. I don't know if you can notice something from the code below:
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public class MazeSolver
{
  public static void main (String [] parms)
  {

    Maze maze = new Maze();
    maze.displayMaze();
    maze.backTracking();
    maze.displayMaze();
  }
}
//**********************************
//*******Position class*************
//**********************************
class Position
{
  private int row;
  private int col;

  public Position()
  {
    row =0;
    col =0;
  }
  public Position (int x, int y)
  {
    row = x;
    col = y;
  }
  public void setRow(int x)
  {
    row = x;
  }
  public void setCol(int y)
  {
    col = y;
  }
  public int getRow()
  {
    return row;
  }
  public int getCol()
  {
    return col;
  }
  //NOTE: wrote for testing purposes, to see the mouse and exit positions
  public String getPosition()
  {
    return row + ", " + col;
  }
}//end Position
//**********************************
//*******Maze element class*********
//**********************************
class MazeElement
{
  private char letter;
  private Position prevPosition;

  public MazeElement(char c, Position p)
  {
    this.letter = c;
    this.prevPosition = p;
  }
  public char getLetter()
  {
    return letter;
  }
  public Position getPosition()
  {
    return prevPosition;
  }
  public void setPosition(Position p)
  {
    this.prevPosition = p;
  }
  public void setLetter(char c)
  {
    this.letter = c;
  }
  public void printElement()
  {
    System.out.print(letter + " ");
  }
}//end MazeElement

//**********************************
//*******Maze class*****************
//**********************************
class Maze
{
  private MazeElement [][] maze;
  private int  numRows;
  private int numCols;
  private Position start;
  private Position exit;



  BufferedReader inFile;
  Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
  String inLine;
  String fileName;
  String [] tokens;

  public Maze()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("Input file name");
      fileName = kbd.next();
      inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
      inLine = inFile.readLine();

      tokens = inLine.trim().split("\\s+");
      numRows = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
      numCols = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
      maze = new MazeElement[numRows][numCols];

      for(int row = 0; inLine != null && row < numRows; row++)
      {
        inLine = inFile.readLine();
        tokens = inLine.trim().split("\\s+");
        for(int col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
        {
          maze[row][col] = new MazeElement(tokens[col].charAt(0),null);
        }
      }
      inFile.close();

      //finding m and e from the maze
      for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) 
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) 
        {
          char letter = maze[i][j].getLetter();
          if(letter == 'm')
          {
            start = new Position(i,j);
          }
          if(letter == 'e')
          {
            exit = new Position(i,j);
          }
        }
      }
    }//end try block
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
      System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

  }//end public Maze()
  public void backTracking()
  {
    Stack<Position> theStack = new Stack<Position>();//initialise stack
    Position goal = exit;
    Position curr;
    MazeElement north, south, east, west;
    int currRow, currCol;
    curr = null;
    boolean foundGoal = false;

    theStack.push(start);

    while((!foundGoal) && (!theStack.isEmpty()))
    {
      curr = theStack.pop();
      currRow = curr.getRow();
      currCol = curr.getCol();

      //check neighbouring positions
      east = maze[currRow][currCol+1];
      south = maze[currRow+1][currCol];
      west = maze[currRow][currCol-1];
      north = maze[currRow-1][currCol];

      //searching clockwise
//setting visited positions to '.', open = '0', wall = '1', exit==goal = 'e'
      if(isValidPosition(east))
      {
        if(east.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          east.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(east.getPosition());
          foundGoal = true;
        }
        else if((!foundGoal)&&(east.getLetter() == '0')&& (east.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
          east.setLetter('.');
          east.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(east.getPosition());
        }
      }
      else if(isValidPosition(south))
      {
        if(south.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          south.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(south.getPosition());
          foundGoal = true;
        }
        else if((!foundGoal)&&(south.getLetter() == '0')&& (south.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
          south.setLetter('.');
          south.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(south.getPosition());
        }
      }
      else if(isValidPosition(west))
      {
        if(west.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          west.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(west.getPosition());
          foundGoal = true;
        }
        else if((!foundGoal)&&(west.getLetter() == '0')&& (west.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
          west.setLetter('.');
          west.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(west.getPosition());
        }
      }
      else if(isValidPosition(north))
      {
        if(north.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          north.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(north.getPosition());
          foundGoal = true;
        }
        else if((!foundGoal)&&(north.getLetter() == '0')&& (north.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
          north.setLetter('.');
          north.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(north.getPosition());
        }
      }
    }//end while

  }
  public void displayMaze()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) 
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) 
      {
        maze[i][j].printElement();
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("start is at " + start.getPosition());
    System.out.println("exit is at " + exit.getPosition()); 
  }//displayMaze()

  public boolean isValidPosition(MazeElement element)
  {
    char wall = '1';
    return (element.getLetter() != wall);
  }
}


//**********************************
//*******Stack<E> class*************
//**********************************
class Stack<E> 
{
  protected Node<E> head; 
  public Stack() 
  {
    head = null;
  } 
  public boolean isEmpty() 
  { 
    return (head == null);
  } 
  public void push(E item) 
  {
    head = new Node<E>(item, head);
  } 
  public E top() 
  { 
    E topItem = null; 
    if (head != null) topItem = head.getData(); 
    return topItem; 
  }
  public E pop() 
  {
    E topItem = top(); 
    if (head != null) head = head.getNext(); 
    return topItem; 
  }
}
//**********************************
//*******Node class*****************
//**********************************
class Node <E>
{
  private E data;
  private Node<E> next;

  public Node ()
  {
    //initializing everything to null at first
    next = null;
    data = null;
  }
  public Node(E data, Node <E> n)
  {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = n;
  }
  public E getData()
  {
    return data;
  }
  public Node <E> getNext()
  {
    return next;
  }
  public void setNext(Node <E> next)
  {
    this.next = next;
  }
}
```

My input file is the following:

```
6 5
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 e 1
1 1 1 0 1
1 m 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

When I print the maze after I call the backTrack() method, my Maze(with m and e positions) becomes:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 e 1 
1 1 1 0 1 
1 m 1 0 1 
1 . 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
start is at 3, 1
exit is at 1, 3
```

The issue is that I do not understand why my curr doesn't move beyond the point '.' in the output. Please help?

Comment: what are the lines like `east.setPosition(curr);` for? if east is the neighbouring position, why are you moving it?

Comment: by east.setPosition(curr) i am trying to say that set the previous position of east to curr because our next position would be east. In essence, East's prevPosition = curr.

Comment: and why do you need to know the previous position? so you can follow it back?

Comment: yes, because i will also write a `pathMarking()` method that prints a 'p' on the path the mouse took

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
if(isValidPosition(east))
{
    if(east.getLetter() == 'e')
    {
        east.setPosition(curr);
        theStack.push(east.getPosition());
        foundGoal = true;
    }
    else if((!foundGoal)&&(east.getLetter() == '0')&& (east.getLetter() != '.'))
    {
        east.setLetter('.');
        theStack.push(east.getPosition());
    }
}
```

Original :
From what I can tell, the only thing that has been pushed into `theStack` is `start`. So, `curr` == `start`. Then, in your conditions, if it meets the directions you do:

`east.setPosition(curr);`
`theStack.push(east.getPosition());`

(Or whichever direction it tests on, in this case it's actually south).

Remember, the first time `curr` == `start`, so you're setting `east.setPosition == curr == start`, which means you push back to the stack `start`.

Now, the code runs again with only 1 thing in the `theStack` and it's the same as it was before, EXCEPT, the character below start is now a '.', so there are no valid directions and your `while` loop breaks.

To fix the code, you'll have to push to `theStack` a `Position` whose values are the direction's and not update the direction position.

Comment: so how do I modify this?

Comment: Updated it again. See the Edit comment. You should be able to just delete the `direction.setPosition(curr)` lines and it'll work.

Comment: my Position class takes in (int row, int column) and you said increment row for South, shouldn't it be `theStack.push(new Position(curr.getRow()+1, curr.getCol());`?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes. I had a typo there anyway(both were .getCol), but the mistake was because I was mapping the coordinates differently. The x-axis actually corresponds to the column #, and y-axis to row #, but in you Position class you have row being x, and column being y. It's inconsistent with typical usage of x & y axis, but as long as you use it consistently it will work. Personally, I'd refactor that at some point. But check my other comment. You don't need to push a `new Position()` at all.

Comment: can you rewrite it in a way I might understand? by replying as an answer? like the `isValidPosition(east)` test condition for example so with that example I will use it to fix the rest of the code. cos i now i have to idea what lines to keep and which to delete. that will be much appreciated

Comment: I edited the answer so the first code is all you need, like you asked. However, I'm on my mobile and can't be certain it formatted properly. If someone could fix it, it'd be great. I'm out now.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code, first to the map loading function, so that every element had a position. You can get rid of this and use `rheStack.push(new Position(row,col));` but i was too lazy.

```
      for(int row = 0; inLine != null && row < numRows; row++)
      {
        inLine = inFile.readLine();
        tokens = inLine.trim().split("\\s+");
        for(int col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
        {
          maze[row][col] = new MazeElement(tokens[col].charAt(0),new Position(row,col));
        }
      }
```

The next change is to the backtracking code. Now in essence you can backtrack using only a stack, however it is not enough to just store the places you have been. For example, after if you first went east and then west, then you need to store that on the stack as well. This makes backtracking more complicated, however programming languages gives us a much easier way of dealing with stacks - *recursion*.

All the parameters passed to a function, and all the temporaries it creates, are stored on a special stack - the program stack. This is the same stack referenced in *StackOverflow*.  Therefore recursive functions have all the same strucutre as a backtracking alogorithm.

So I broke you backtracking algorithm to make it recursive

```
  public void backTracking()
  {
    Stack<Position> theStack = new Stack<Position>();//initialise stack
    theStack.push(start);
    //pass it the stack and the goal
    backTrackingRecursive(theStack, exit);
  }
  public boolean backTrackingRecursive(Stack<Position> theStack, Position goal)
  {
      //displayMaze();
      Position curr = theStack.top();
      int currRow = curr.getRow();
      int currCol = curr.getCol();

      //setting visited positions to '.', open = '0', wall = '1', exit==goal = 'e'

      for(int i = 0; i != 4; i++)
      {

          //forget this code, it is only to avoid writing out north, south, etc
          int col = currCol;
          int row = currRow;

          if(i%2 == 1)
            col += ((i==1)?1:-1);
          else
            row += ((i==2)?1:-1);

        //check it is a valid position, if not continue
        if(row < 0 || row >= numRows || col < 0 || col >= numCols) continue;

        MazeElement next = maze[row][col];

        if(next.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          theStack.push(next.getPosition());
          return true;
        }
        else if(next.getLetter() == '0')
        {
          theStack.push(next.getPosition());
          next.setLetter('.');
          if(backTrackingRecursive(theStack,goal))
          {
              //success!
              return true;
          } else {
              //try a different path
              next.setLetter('0');
              theStack.pop();
          }
        }  
      }

      return false;     
  }
```

The `backTrackingRecursive` function does all the work, and we simply push the next position on to the stack before continuing. We don't even need to have the stack at all but I kept it for simplicity.

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 e 1 
1 1 1 0 1 
1 m 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
start is at 3, 1
exit is at 1, 3
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 e 1 
1 1 1 . 1 
1 m 1 . 1 
1 . . . 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
start is at 3, 1
exit is at 1, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly!!!! i followed the comments from the first answer and found this solution! thank you @CreationEdge

```
if(isValidPosition(east))
      {
        if(east.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          foundGoal = true;
        }
         if((!foundGoal)&&(east.getLetter() == '0')&& (east.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
          east.setLetter('.');
          east.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(new Position(curr.getRow(), curr.getCol()+1));
        }
      }
       if(isValidPosition(south))
      {
        if(south.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          System.out.println(south.getLetter());
          foundGoal = true;
        }
         if((!foundGoal)&&(south.getLetter() == '0')&& (south.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
          south.setLetter('.');
          south.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(new Position(curr.getRow() + 1, curr.getCol()));
        }
      }
       if(isValidPosition(west))
      {
        if(west.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          foundGoal = true;
        }
         if((!foundGoal)&&(west.getLetter() == '0')&& (west.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
           west.setLetter('.');
           west.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(new Position(curr.getRow(), curr.getCol()-1));
        }
      }
       if(isValidPosition(north))
      {
        if(north.getLetter() == 'e')
        {
          foundGoal = true;
        }
         if((!foundGoal)&&(north.getLetter() == '0')&& (north.getLetter() != '.'))
        {
           north.setLetter('.');
           north.setPosition(curr);
          theStack.push(new Position(curr.getRow() - 1, curr.getCol()));
        }
      }
```